# Android splash screens as images

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I want to make image as a splash screen. What sizes should I make to make splash screen image fill whole screen without stretching supporting horizontal and vertical orientations and all densities. Also where should I write code to indicate which images are splash screens for each size and orientation?

iOS has that kind of feature to select launch images in the properties
to set all required image sizes to support all screens and all orientations,without writing any lines of code
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 9-patch.
9-patch images can stretch in 4 directions if you want.
It will solve your problem. Xamarin can also use 9-patch images as splash screen.

[Example Documentation](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-android-9-patch-image-splashscreen/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use vector asset images which could be helpful for both iOS and Android
For reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html